# How to return options of react-select during typing something inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

Hi i have issue with react-select component. I am using this package and i am sending to this select options. I need to filter original object when i typing to this select.

This is my component. just one method and render

```
selectLabel = [
        {
            label: '',
            options: [{
                label: '-Nič-',
                value: null,
            }],
        },
        {
            label: 'Balíky',
            options: [],
        },
        {
            label: 'Témy',
            options: [],
        },
        {
            label: 'Časti',
            options: [],
        },
        {
            label: 'Úlohy',
            options: [],
        },
    ];

 componentDidMount() {
        this.createLabelsForSearchBox();
    }


    createLabelsForSearchBox(){
        this.props.data.packages.forEach((pck) => {
            this.selectLabel[1].options.push({value: pck, label: pck.name});
        });

        this.props.data.packages.forEach((pckg) =>{
            pckg.themes.forEach((theme) =>{
                this.selectLabel[2].options.push({value: theme, label: theme.name});
            });
        });

        this.props.data.packages.forEach((pckg) =>{
            pckg.themes.forEach((theme) =>{
                theme.themeParts.forEach((part)=>{
                    this.selectLabel[3].options.push({value: part, label: part.name});
                });
            });
        });

        this.props.data.packages.forEach((pckg) =>{
            pckg.themes.forEach((theme) =>{
                theme.themeParts.forEach((part)=>{
                   part.knowledges.forEach((knowledge) => {
                        this.selectLabel[4].options.push({value: knowledge, label: knowledge.textPreview});
                    });
                });
            });
        });
    }


render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Form className={'d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-start mt-2 mt-md-0'}>
                    <div className={'px-2 d-inline-block d-md-flex'}>
                        <div className={'d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mb-2'}>
                            <Form.Group controlId="searchInput" className={'m-0 mr-2 flex-grow-1'}>
                                <Select
                                    options={this.selectLabel}
                                    onChange={((e) => console.log(e))}
                                    className={'search-input'}
                                />
                            </Form.Group>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Now i would like to make some changeMethod for this select where i will get filtered options from this select. Select is filtering inside somehow data but i can't find any option to get this filtered list outside. Is that possible? Or is there other way to do this maybe better please?

Working snippet here: https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-agnesi-sfhcs?file=/src/App.js

Why I need this? I have to filter this:
[image: My component]

It is my component and it consist of 4 subtypes Packages,Themes,Part,Exercises... And I need to filter them in runtime

Comment: can you please add aworking snippet please ?

Comment: Of course https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-agnesi-sfhcs?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Now i can see one problem. onChangeMethod runs only if i pick something from selectbox lsit. So Have I do it different way?

Comment: I am close I believe if we use `CreatableSelect` component we have a way